# Project Euler 2# - strange output

Tags: c

I've tried to solve problem 2 on Project Euler in C. This is the first possible solution that came to my mind, and, in fact, it gives as an output the right answer. The problem is that each time I run my program it gives me a different output, which is either "2" or "4613732" that is the right answer. Sorry for my poor english, can you help me find out what's wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int n, n1 = 1, n2 = 2, sum = 2;
  while(n<4000000){
     n = n1 + n2; /*calculate the next number of the series*/
     n1 = n2;
     n2 = n;
     if(n%2 == 0){
        sum = sum + n; /*if the number it's even add it to the main sum*/
      }
    }
    printf("The sum is %d\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: Since you didn't initialize `n`, it can start with any value. If it starts with a value `<4000000`, then the loop runs and you get the right answer. If it starts with a value `>=4000000`, then the loop doesn't run, and the output is 2 because you started with `sum=2`. This is known as [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105123).

Answer (score 2):

You didn't initialize `n`; when you get the right answer, it means you got lucky.

Comment: I see...it was a stupid error, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int evenFibSum(int i=1,int j=2)
{
    const int max = 3999999;
    int eventsum = 2;
    int sum = 0;
    while (sum < max)
    {
        sum = i + j;
        i = j;
        j = sum;

        if (sum % 2 == 0)
            eventsum +=sum;
    }
    return eventsum;
}
```

For more efficient solution apply following logic

```
Fibbonaci Series =>  1   2  3  5  8  13  21  34  55  89 144
Index            =>  0   1  2  3  4  5   6    7   8   9  10
```

To get even fibbonanci addition I have to add following index values[1 4 7 10]
Here I am sensing some pattern

[1 4 7 10] =>   I need advance index by 3

so how to advance index by 3

```
//  k = i+j = > 3  13  55
//  i = k+j  => 5  21  89
//  j = k+i  => 8  34  144

int evenFibSumx(int i=1,int j=2)
{
    const int max = 3999999;
    int eventsum = 2;
    int k= 0;
    while (1)
    {
        k = i + j;
        i = k + j;
        j = k + i;
        if(i >= max)
            break;
        if (j%2 == 0)
            eventsum +=j;
    }
    return eventsum;
}


int main()
{
     std::cout << evenFibSum();
     std::cout << evenFibSumx();

}
```